# Copy data from struct X to struct Y but convert one field to different type

Tags: go

I am new to statically-typed languages, i am trying to teach myself golang and i am making a small rest api project to learn.

I am making a call to a GRPC service like so

```
func (m *MarketsService) GetAllMarkets(ctx context.Context) (*markets.AllData, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Hour)
    defer cancel()

    r, err := m.client.GetAllData(ctx, &markets.NoParams{})

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return r, nil
}
```

I am sending the response to the front end though the Gin server like so and it works fine. The front end receives the data.

```
    func getAllMarketsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
        now := time.Now().UnixNano()
        code := http.StatusOK

        allMarkets, err := GRPCMarketsService.GetAllMarkets(context.Background())

        if err != nil {
            err := err.(*errorHTTP)
            sendResponse(c, "", now, err.code, err.message)
            return
        }

        sendResponse(c, "", now, code, &response)
    }
```

However some of the params from the GRPC response are enums. I would like to convert the enums to strings before i send the response with Gin. Below is the proto message i receive from the GRPC call

```
type AllData struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    MarketInfos        []*MarketInfo        `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=MarketInfos,proto3" json:"marketInfos"`
    LeverageProfiles   []*LeverageProfile   `protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=LeverageProfiles,proto3" json:"leverageProfiles"`
    ProtectionProfiles []*ProtectionProfile `protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=ProtectionProfiles,proto3" json:"protectionProfiles"`
    VolumeProfiles     []*VolumeProfile     `protobuf:"bytes,4,rep,name=VolumeProfiles,proto3" json:"volumeProfiles"`
}

type MarketInfo struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    MarketId                 string             `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=marketId,proto3" json:"marketId"`
    Name                     string             `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name"`
    Base                     string             `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=base,proto3" json:"base"`
    Quote                    string             `protobuf:"bytes,4,opt,name=quote,proto3" json:"quote"`
    Symbol                   string             `protobuf:"bytes,21,opt,name=symbol,proto3" json:"symbol"`
    PricePrecision           int32              `protobuf:"varint,5,opt,name=pricePrecision,proto3" json:"pricePrecision"`
    QuantityPrecision        int32              `protobuf:"varint,6,opt,name=quantityPrecision,proto3" json:"quantityPrecision"`
    PriceTickSize            string             `protobuf:"bytes,7,opt,name=PriceTickSize,proto3" json:"priceTickSize"`
    QuantityTickSize         string             `protobuf:"bytes,8,opt,name=quantityTickSize,proto3" json:"quantityTickSize"`
    MarketTakeBound          string             `protobuf:"bytes,9,opt,name=marketTakeBound,proto3" json:"marketTakeBound"`
    OrderTypes               []OrderType        `protobuf:"varint,10,rep,packed,name=orderTypes,proto3,enum=markets.OrderType" json:"orderTypes"`
    MarketStatus             MarketStatus       `protobuf:"varint,11,opt,name=marketStatus,proto3,enum=markets.MarketStatus" json:"marketStatus"`
    MarketType               MarketType         `protobuf:"varint,12,opt,name=marketType,proto3,enum=markets.MarketType" json:"marketType"`
    TimeInForce              []TimeInForce      `protobuf:"varint,13,rep,packed,name=timeInForce,proto3,enum=markets.TimeInForce" json:"timeInForce"`
    DefaultVolumeProfile     *VolumeProfile     `protobuf:"bytes,14,opt,name=defaultVolumeProfile,proto3" json:"defaultVolumeProfile"`
    DefaultProtectionProfile *ProtectionProfile `protobuf:"bytes,15,opt,name=defaultProtectionProfile,proto3" json:"defaultProtectionProfile"`
    DefaultLeverageProfile   *LeverageProfile   `protobuf:"bytes,16,opt,name=defaultLeverageProfile,proto3" json:"defaultLeverageProfile"`
    IsOpen                   bool               `protobuf:"varint,17,opt,name=isOpen,proto3" json:"isOpen"`
    NextOpeCloseInterval     int32              `protobuf:"varint,18,opt,name=nextOpeCloseInterval,proto3" json:"nextOpeCloseInterval"`
    InterestRateShort        string             `protobuf:"bytes,19,opt,name=interestRateShort,proto3" json:"interestRateShort"`
    InterestRateLong         string             `protobuf:"bytes,20,opt,name=interestRateLong,proto3" json:"interestRateLong"`
}
```

`OrderTypes` is a slice of enums that i would like to convert to strings before sending to the front end. My question is, is there a way that i can change the type of `OrderTypes` to a slice of strings without manually creating a whole new struct.

Here is my current solution, its very verbose and i feel there must be a better way to do it (and it it more dynamically so i do not have to update the code if a new param is added to the proto). Ideally it would be something generic as i have other messages that are similar (have enums i want to convert to strings)

```
    type MaketInfosShadowd struct {
        markets.MarketInfo
        OrderTypes   []string
        TimeInForce  []string
        MarketStatus string
        MarketType   string
    }

    type AllMarketsResponse struct {
        LeverageProfiles   []*markets.LeverageProfile
        ProtectionProfiles []*markets.ProtectionProfile
        VolumeProfiles     []*markets.VolumeProfile
        MarketInfos        []*MaketInfosShadowd
    }

    func getAllMarketsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
        now := time.Now().UnixNano()
        code := http.StatusOK

        allMarkets, err := GRPCMarketsService.GetAllMarkets(context.Background())

        response := &AllMarketsResponse{}
        response.LeverageProfiles = allMarkets.LeverageProfiles
        response.ProtectionProfiles = allMarkets.ProtectionProfiles
        response.VolumeProfiles = allMarkets.VolumeProfiles

        for _, val := range allMarkets.MarketInfos {
            infos := MaketInfosShadowd{}
            infos.MarketStatus = val.MarketStatus.String()
            infos.MarketType = val.MarketType.String()
            infos.Name = val.Name
            infos.Base = vale.Base
            infos.Quote = vale.Quote
            infos.Symbol = vale.Symbol
            infos.PricePrecision = vale.PricePrecision
            infos.QuantityPrecision = vale.QuantityPrecision
            // I have left the rest out for brevity

            for _, val := range val.OrderTypes {
                infos.OrderTypes = append(infos.OrderTypes, val.String())
            }

            for _, val := range val.TimeInForce {
                infos.TimeInForce = append(infos.TimeInForce, val.String())
            }
            response.MarketInfos = append(response.MarketInfos, &infos)
        }

        if err != nil {
            err := err.(*errorHTTP)
            sendResponse(c, "", now, err.code, err.message)
            return
        }

        sendResponse(c, "", now, code, &response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are JSON annotations, you can use the protoJSON package to quickly marshal data into JSON. You can then unmarshal the JSON into a Go struct using json.Unmarshal. However, your code appears to be reasonable.